# How do I use a docker build cache with nuget when switching users?

Tags: nuget-package-restore, docker-buildkit

I build my docker image by first building my dotnet app using the root user. Then to build the test target I switch to a test user. I want to take advantage of the docker cache mount type for the nuget restore in order to save pulling all the nugets all over again when dotnet test runs in my runUnitTests.sh. This works between the build and publish targets (dotnet publish) since they are both running under root user. However, it fails when I switch to the test user and dotnet tries to restore again.

Project structure:

```
/MyApp.sln (points to below csproj)
/src/app/MyApp.Main/MyApp.Main.csproj
/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj
/src/test/runUnitTests.sh
/src/docker/Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile (simplified):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim AS build-env
WORKDIR /appcode
COPY . ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-packages,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
  --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-cache,target=/root/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache \
  --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-plugins,target=/root/.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache \
  --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-scratch,target=/tmp/NuGetScratch \
  dotnet restore

# Unit Testing
FROM build-env AS unit-test-env
ARG UID=999
RUN useradd -u ${UID} --shell /bin/bash -m test-user \
  && chown -R test-user /appcode/*
USER test-user
WORKDIR /appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-packages,target=/home/test-user/.nuget/packages \
  --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-cache,target=/home/test-user/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache \
  --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-plugins,target=/home/test-user/.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache \
  --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-migrations,target=/home/test-user/.local/share/NuGet/Migrations \
  --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-scratch,target=/tmp/NuGetScratch \
  dotnet restore
CMD ["/appcode/src/test/runUnitTests.sh"]
```

Error:

```
$ docker build -f src/docker/Dockerfile -t my-app:1 --target=unit-test-env --rm .
[+] Building 7.4s (12/12) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.18kB                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim                                                                                                                                                     0.2s
 => [build-env 1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim@sha256:79042d5b225ec9f40a4144f6a60492aeccf5eea1d47a390e428c736cd368351c                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring context: 101.18kB                                                                                                                                                                                               0.1s
 => CACHED [build-env 2/4] WORKDIR /appcode                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [build-env 3/4] COPY . ./                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => [build-env 4/4] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-packages,target=/root/.nuget/packages   --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-cache,target=/root/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache   --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-plugins,target  5.0s
 => [unit-test-env 1/4] RUN useradd -u 999 --shell /bin/bash -m test-user   && chown -R test-user /appcode/*   && chmod -R a+x /appcode/src/deploy/*   && mkdir -p /output/report   && chown test-user /output   && chown test-use  0.6s
 => [unit-test-env 2/4] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-scratch,target=/tmp/NuGetScratch chown -R test-user /tmp                                                                                                               0.2s 
 => [unit-test-env 3/4] WORKDIR /appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => ERROR [unit-test-env 4/4] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-packages,target=/home/test-user/.nuget/packages   --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-cache,target=/home/test-user/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache   --mount=type=cach  0.8s 
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 > [unit-test-env 4/4] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-packages,target=/home/test-user/.nuget/packages   --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-cache,target=/home/test-user/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache   --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-plugins,target=/home/test-user/.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache   --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-migrations,target=/home/test-user/.local/share/NuGet/Migrations   --mount=type=cache,id=nuget-scratch,target=/tmp/NuGetScratch   dotnet restore:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018: The "WarnForInvalidProjectsTask" task failed unexpectedly. [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set permission while creating /tmp/NuGetScratch, errno=1. [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Common.NuGetEnvironment.<GetFolderPath>g__CreateSharedDirectory|6_0(String path) [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Common.NuGetEnvironment.GetFolderPath(NuGetFolderPath folder) [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Common.PathUtility.CheckIfFileSystemIsCaseInsensitive() [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor) [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Common.PathUtility.get_IsFileSystemCaseInsensitive() [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Common.PathUtility.GetStringComparerBasedOnOS() [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Build.Tasks.WarnForInvalidProjectsTask.Execute() [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
#11 0.815 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.406/NuGet.targets(394,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/appcode/src/test/MyApp.UnitTests/MyApp.UnitTests.csproj]
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore]: exit code: 1
```

I've tried adding `RUN chown -R test-user /tmp` as root after test-user was created. I've also tried `RUN rm -rf /tmp/NuGetScratch`. Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

- Please Check Permission of /tmp by using command

```
ls -ld /tmp
```

default should be 1777 drwxrwxrwt
Note 1 = sticky bit

- try to correct permissions by follow step

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
#or
chmod a+trwx /tmp
```

Comment: drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 Aug 24 21:22 /tmp

Comment: drwxrwxrwt is the permissions on that directory and chmod doesnt do much since they already are. I think the big problem is the way nuget manages these lock files and that I'm changing users but using the same cache of files. I'm unclear how to handle nuget lock and migration files like this as it's kind of abstracted away.